# Using data attribute to select panel

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a set of tabs in jQuery, and would like to create a generic rule to select the correct panel when the matching link is selected. I am trying to avoid writing specific links for each panel.

This is what I have so far, so when you click on the 'features' link it should show the panel with ID of features.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ajIvr

The jquery code

```
$(function(){
  $('a').click(function(){
    $(this).data('sec').show();
  });
});
```

Any help wpould be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build your ID selector properly:

```
$(function(){
  $('a').click(function(){
     $('#' + $(this).data('sec')).show();
  });
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rontg

Answer (score 0):

change to:

```
$('#' + $(this).data('sec')).show();
```